# Stringing test results in towers with weak base

Tags: print-quality

As you can see, no stringing! But the base of each tower is deformed, non-circular, and extremely weak. The tops of the towers are perfectly circular, so I don't believe it is entirely an X, Y axis issue.

This is PLA at ~195 °C with a 64 °C bed on a QIDI X-MAX. I have tried this with multiple copies of the print on the bed which does not solve the problem, so I don't believe it is a layer-cooling issue. Also tried different temperatures, Z-adjust, and re-leveled multiple times. Any thoughts on the cause of this?

[image: Photo of a string tower model with no stringing present]

Comment: This is an odd issue I haven't seen before, but your bed temperature is quite high for PLA and the nozzle temperature is quite low. These could be factors.

Comment: How did this ever happen?

Answer (score 3):

The warping on the base's corners suggests too much heat on the bed. You should try the same print but with the bed turned off since you're using PLA (if you're worried about adhesion you can use hairspray/glue stick to keep the print in place). If the print comes out okay then lower your bed temperature (I generally use 50 °C) or consider carrying on with the bed off + adhesive combination instead.

Comment: Also, on QIDI X-MAX, since there's an enclosure, as well as lowering the bed temperature, maybe try to leave the door open for some filament (such as PLA).